# What is the best practice for making a get request in node with arguments?

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I'm attempting to call this end point: `https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash` in the following manner using the request-response module:

```
api.get('/transaction/:hash', (req, res) => {

    const hash = (req.params.hash);
    let uri = 'https://blockchain.info/rawtx/' + hash;

    rp(uri).then(function (txInfo) {
                let result = JSON.parse(txInfo);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of calling an end point as opposed to just concatenating the argument?

Comment: Can use string templating: `let uri = \`https://blockchain.info/rawtx/${req.params.hash}\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is clean enough. Your other option is `.concat()` but that's just slower. If you prefer templating and are in an es6 supported environment then you can do  let `uri = 'https://blockchain.info/rawtx/${hash}'`; as suggested in the above comment. But like I said, I think the way you are doing it now is fit for purpose.